# Returning function object or anonymous object with same attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am unable to comprehend whether the following two styles have any difference, which is more prefferable or are they just visually different.

**STYLE 1 - Exporting a anonymous function that returns a javascript object with functions as attributes**

```
module.exports = function(logger,db,config){

    return {
        getAByB : function(b,cb){
            logger.log(b);
            cb(undefined,'someting');
        },


        getName : function(cb){
             db.fetch(function(res){
                 cb(res)
             });
        }
    }
}
```

**STYLE 2 - Exporting a function with attributes (honestly i don't understand why function name is used in return)**

```
module.exports = function Something(logger,db,config){

        Something.getAByB = function(b,cb){
            logger.log(b);
            cb(undefined,'someting');
        }


        Something.getName = function(cb){
             db.fetch(function(res){
                 cb(res)
             });
        }

        return Something;
}
```

Also please explain what this 2nd style is trying to achieve.

Comment: FYI, javascript calls things like `getAByB` and `getName` "properties", not "attributes".

Comment: ah ok , new to this ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Both are **not** the same.

The first will create a new object with the methods and properties you've specified. This will only be accessible as the return value.

```
var x = module.exports(1, 2, 3); // Object {getAByB: function...
console.log( module.exports.getAByB ); // undefined
module.exports(1, 2, 3).getAByB(4, 5); // works
```

The second will set all the methods to be chainable calls on the `module.exports` method itself as well as an instantly-chainable object:

```
var y = module.exports(1, 2, 3); // function Something...
console.log( module.exports.getAByB ); // function getAByB...
module.exports(1, 2, 3).getAByB(4, 5); // works
```

Comment: The second returns a function object with the methods on it.  It's just as chainable as the first. Remember that, in javascript, functions are objects too.

Comment: Ah, my undefined warning was coming from a call from the `getAByB` function :) Good catch. Updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

Both versions return a function which takes (logger,db,config) arguments, and then returns a value with getAByB and getName methods. However, there are potentially important differences.

The first version returns a brand new object each time. The second version returns a reference to the *same* object each time, and overwrites the object's methods! Consider the following code (I've assumed that the code examples are a module called "database-connector"):

```
var databaseConnector = require("database-connector");

var db1Logger = console.log.bind(console, "Db1 log:");
var db1 = ...;
var db1Connection = databaseConnector(db1Logger, db1, {});

var db2Logger = console.log.bind(console, "Db2 log:");
var db2 = ...;
var db2Connection = databaseConnector(db2Logger, db2, {});
```

With the first version of the module, this will work fine. However, with the second version of the code, db1Connection and db2Connection will both be the same value! If you call `db1Connection.getAByB` or `db1Connection.getName`, then db2Logger and db2 will be used instead because db2Connection's initialization overwrote db1Connection's methods.

Another difference is that with the second version of the module, db1Connection and db2Connection are also both equal to the databaseConnector function, and can be called directly to overwrite their methods again. I don't believe that would be a useful feature or was intended.